# Refunding a flight ticket, bought via third party

Tags: air-travel, refunds, travel-agents

I am planning to fly from Dubai in November. I haven't bought a ticket yet. I got a $100 gift coupon from a friend to buy ticket a specific third-party agency/aggregator, that I would like to use soon.

Therefore I am choosing an airline, that would allow me to refund this ticket directly through them, even if the ticket itself was bought from 3rd-party agent?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you hold one ticket or two? If two, which ticket are you trying to refund? In either case, have you asked the airline directly?

Comment: I rephrased my question. I anticipated it would be unclear.

Comment: The answer, I'm afraid, will depend upon the policies of the airline, and the arrangement the airline has with ticket agency/aggregator from whom the gift coupon was purchased. Without knowing these policies and rules, the answer is unknown. You could ask the airline. Further: the gift coupon is undoubtedly set up for you to buy your ticket from the third-party agency/aggregator. Why don't you use the gift coupon that way?

Comment: I don’t think there are any airlines that will refund a ticket directly if bought through a third party. They will always refer to the original reseller, and there will usually be additional restrictions, especially if vouchers were involved. The only alternative could be for them to issue a voucher for future travel instead.